# Reduction potential of water

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

I can't understand what is meant by the reduction potential of water. In Electrolysis of water decomposition of water takes place as a result of which
$H+$ and $OH-$ are furnished. They migrate towards cathode and anode respectively where they get reduced and oxidised. Each of them have their respective reduction potentials. Same in case of $\ce{AgCl}$ what is meant by reduction potential of $\ce{AgCl}$ as it contains both cationic and anionic part.

Comment: See if that addresses your question, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112840/why-is-reduction-potential-of-water-2h%E2%82%82o-2e%E2%81%BB-%E2%86%92-h%E2%82%82-2oh%E2%81%BB-is-0-83-insted-o

Comment: @AChem the link you shared doesn't actually answer my question. It is based on calculations and I have done many problems but I have doubt regarding the intuition behind terms like reduction potential of water

Comment: Okay. I will try to address it.

Comment: In the $\ce{AgCl/Ag}$ half-cell, the chlorine atom does not change its oxidation number. Only $\ce{Ag}$ is reduced from +$1$ to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When electrochemists talk about the reduction potential of water, it specifically refers to an *isolated* half-cell. They are referring to the cathodic reaction only. When water gains electrons (from a source), it forms hydrogen and hydroxide ions.

$$\ce{2 H2O + 2 e- <=> H2 + 2 OH-}\label{rxn:2}\tag{1}$$

so there no cations here.

As you know, half-cells cannot exist alone, you need another half-cell to complete the circuit. The other half-cell is the hydrogen electrode whose value is arbitrarily set to zero by the German electrochemists more than a century ago.

You can see here how it is practically measured.

https://www.nemi.gov/methods/method_summary/5456/

Comment: Reduction of water is *not* set to zero. Look at the equation carefully, there are no protons there! https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/112840/why-is-reduction-potential-of-water-2h%E2%82%82o-2e%E2%81%BB-%E2%86%92-h%E2%82%82-2oh%E2%81%BB-is-0-83-insted-o

Comment: SHE is set to zero at pH=0.

Answer (score 0):

Reduction potential is defined as the tendency of a *species* to get reduced by gaining an electron and the value is standardized with a reference to the **Standard** **Electron Potential** (SHE) of Hydrogen having a value of 0.
Now, the reduction potentials are defined for *isolated half cells*.

For instance, in case of electrolysis of water, the cations and anions generated are H+ and OH- respectively. These ions migrate towards cathode and anode where they get oxidised and reduced. Here,the reduction potentials can be found out individually!

Same in case of AgCl. AgCl after ionisation gives Ag+ and Cl- ions which move towards cathode and anode, and then we can find out the reduction potentials individually. (We can also find the oxidation potentials of the above-mentioned species, but reduction is generally used as a convention, so we use that)

```
                      AgCl ⇌ Ag+ + Cl¯
```

The species which undergoes reduction (here, Cl-), has a *positive reduction* *potential*, as it is easier to be reduced whereas, the species which undergoes oxidation (here, Ag+) can also be defined in terms of reduction potential, but in this case, it will have a *negative reduction potential* as it is easier to oxidise Ag+ than to reduce it! (The negative sign means that the tendency of the species to get reduced is less than hydrogen and the tendency to oxidize is more than hydrogen.)

However, the reduction potential of a compound (AgCl) on the whole doesn't exist!